# How to take screenshot of webpage and paste it in a Word document?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to take screenshot of the web page and paste it in Word. Following is the code written

```
    Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
    Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
    Private Const VK_SNAPSHOT As Byte = 44
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
    Private Const SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3
    Private Const VK_LCONTROL As Long = &HA2
    Private Const VK_V = &H56
    Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2
    Sub Sample()
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorerMedium
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.navigate "https://staging-site.com/"

    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until objIE.readyState = 4

    Dim hwnd As Long, IECaption As String

    '~~> Get the caption of IE
    IECaption = objIE.document.Title

    '~~> Get handle of IE
    hwnd = FindWindow(IECaption, vbNullString)

    If hwnd = 0 Then
    MsgBox "IE Window Not found!"
    Exit Sub
    Else
    '~~> Maximize IE
    ShowWindow hwnd, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED
    End If
    Sleep 3000
    DoEvents

    '~~> Take a snapshot
    Call keybd_event(VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, 0, 0)

Dim SystemDateTime As String

sPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop"

Set wordobj = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Set objDoc = wordobj.Documents.Add

SystemDateTime = Replace(Replace(Now, "/", ""), ":", "")

objDoc.SaveAs (sPath & "\Student Blue Waiver " & SystemDateTime)

wordobj.Visible = True

Set objSelection = wordobj.Selection

'Paste into Word
objSelection.Paste
objDoc.Save
End Sub
```

But the below variable 'hwnd' always returns 0 even though IE windows with caption is visible

```
hwnd = FindWindow(IECaption, vbNullString)
If hwnd = 0 Then
MsgBox "IE Window Not found!"
Exit Sub
```

I think IECaption is getting only the title of the window that might be an issue to FindWindow with desired title

Comment: You *think*, or you *know*?  If you debug this code, what do you actually observe with the `IECaption` value versus the IE browser window?

Comment: IECaption has the value "Select University" but when I hover mouse on IE tab it shows "Select University www.staging-site.com/......"

Comment: What happens if you use `FindWindow` with the full title from IE tab? Is your IE have multiple tabs open at once (this will be problematic, I think).

Comment: I closed all the IE windows and tried, but still the variable hwnd returns 0

Comment: any idea how to get the full title from IE tab ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're passing wrong arguments to the `FindWindow` API function

The first argument should be `"IEFrame"` and the *second* argument should be the window name. In your code, you're passing a the doc title as classname and an empty string (`vbNullString`) as the window name!

NB I used `CreateObject` to instantiate InternetExplorer.Application class. This may be slightly different from your `InternetExplorerMedium`, I don't know.

I also found that I have to append `" - Internet Explorer"` to the caption value, otherwise it can't be found.

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Sub foo()
Dim objIE As Object
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.navigate "http://cnn.com"

    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until objIE.readyState = 4

    Dim hwnd As Long, IECaption As String

    '~~> Get the caption of IE
    IECaption = objIE.Document.Title & " - Internet Explorer"

    '~~> Get handle of IE
    hwnd = FindWindow("IEFrame", IECaption)

    If hwnd = 0 Then
    MsgBox "IE Window Not found!"
    Exit Sub
    Else
```

Comment: IT WORKED !! Thanks David